# regex does not like out#

Tags: java, regex

I write the following code o remove all hashtag words from my text:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out
            .println(removeHashtag("Got an infection in my eye. Pharmacist thinks something bitten me. This wouldn't have happened under Simeone. Wenger a#sarcasm #wengerin"));

}

public static String removeHashtag(String commentstr) {
    String arrWord[] = commentstr.split(" ");
    String sentenceWithoutHash = commentstr;
    System.out.println(sentenceWithoutHash);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrWord.length; i++) {
        if (arrWord[i].contains("#")) {
            String regex = "\\s*\\" + arrWord[i] + "\\b\\s*";
            sentenceWithoutHash = sentenceWithoutHash.replaceAll(regex, "");
        }
    }
    return sentenceWithoutHash;
}
```

But this code does not work wih this text

```
Got an infection in my eye. Pharmacist thinks something bitten me. This wouldn't have happened under Simeone. Wenger out#sarcasm #wengerin"
```

it seems that regex does not like out#

Can anyone help?

Comment: @anubhava text without anyword containing hashtag

Comment: So full `out#sarcasm` should be removed?

Comment: @anubhava yes it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to remove any word containing `#`:

```
String rep = str.replaceAll("\\s*\\w*#\\w*\\s*", "");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tP8pQ0/1)

Answer (score 1):

This will work as per your condition

```
((?:[^\s]+)?#[^\s]+)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xI0iA4/1)**

```
String x = str.replaceAll("((?:[^\\s]+)?#[^\\s]+)", "")
```